# How to show grid with customer and customer's attributes details in magento 2

Tags: customer, grid, backend, magento2.2.7

I wish to show customer name,email and some customer attributes values in a separate grid please provide me a solution, how to replace a below code to show customer and its attribute values.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $model = $this->_model->create()->getCollection();

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**After prepare collection you need to define columns**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'database_field_name',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'database_field_name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
      $this->addColumn(
        'contact_email',
        [
            'header' => __('Contact Email'),
            'index' => 'contact_email',
        ]
        );

        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('company/*/exportCsv', ['_current' => true]), __('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType($this->getUrl('company/*/exportExcel', ['_current' => true]), __('Excel XML'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response, I  need to replace the _prepareCollection function() not prepare columns(), Please read the post once again